# angular Call to pipe from feature module produces error

Tags: angular

Angular cannot find my pipe even though it is imported and declared in the application module.

app.module.ts

```
import { PercentSavedPipe } from './shared/pipes/percent-saved.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PercentSavedPipe
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Pipe is called from template of a feature module:

```
<small class="ml-1">
   ({{product.price | percentSaved:product.list_price |
      currency:'USD':'symbol-narrow'}}%)
</small>
```

Produces the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'percentSaved' could not be found ("</small>
<small class="ml-1">
   [ERROR ->]({{product.price | percentSaved:product.list_price |"): 
    ng:///BrandModule/BrandComponent.html@167:3
   Error: Template parse errors:
  The pipe 'percentSaved' could not be found ("</small>
   <small class="ml-1">
```

percent-saved.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'percentSaved'
})
export class PercentSavedPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(price: number, list_price: number): number {
    return 100 - (100 * price / list_price);
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you include the pipe code snippet as well please ?

Comment: The pipe is included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In angular `declarations` types — `Components`, `Directives` and `Pipes` — can only be used by `Component`s declared inside that `Module`. If you are using your `Pipe` in some `Feature` module then you have also need to `declare` that pipe in `feature` module by adding it to the `declarations` array.